# summernote javascript code in content is not working

Tags: javascript, summernote, html-editor

I have javascript code along with plain content in my summernote. now, 
(1) when I do code view in summernote, put javascript code and come back to normal view, it loads the javascript content(basically it has form) outside the summernote. 
(2) Also, when I am saving it to DB, it doesn't give me that whole JS content along with other content at the controller.

my content with JS code sample which I want to save to DB.

```
lorel Ipsum is simply a dummied text of typesetting industry.

        <!--[if lte IE 8]>    
    <script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//test.net/forms/test.js"></script>    
    <![endif]-->   
    <script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.test.net/forms/test2.js"></script>
    <script>
      hbspt.forms.create({
                    portalId: "11111",
                    formId: "1111111"
    });    
    </script>
```

Thanks